# Pegar o dados pesquisaFornecedor e colocar no form cadastro de produtos

Tags: c#, winforms

Não consigo pegar os dados do form PesqFornecedor e colocar no formCadastroProdu

Meu projeto é em C# Windows Forms em 4 camadas.

fiz assim

[image: Tela Cadastro de Peças]

frmCadastroPecas

```
    private void pctLocalizaFornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmPesquisarFornecedor pesqFornec = new frmPesquisarFornecedor();

        pesqFornec.Show(this);


    }
```

[image: Pesquisar Fornecedor]

frmPesquisarFornecedor

```
    public partial class frmPesquisarFornecedor : Form
{
    private Form codFornec;
    public frmPesquisarFornecedor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public frmPesquisarFornecedor(Form codFornec)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.codFornec = codFornec;


    }


    private void frmPesquisarFornecedor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CarregaGrid();

    }

    private void CarregaGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            IList<FornecedorDTO> listaFornecDTO = new List<FornecedorDTO>();

            listaFornecDTO = new FornecedorModel().CargaFornecedor();// Cria uma estancia do Objeto UsuarioModel
            dgvFornecedor.AutoGenerateColumns = false;// Não vai gerar colunas automaticamente
            dgvFornecedor.DataSource = listaFornecDTO;// carrega o meu grid DataSource ListaUsuarioDTO



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void frmPesquisarFornecedor_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Não sei o que colocar AQUI ??????
    }



}
```

}

precisava carregar o fornecedor selecionado na frmCadastroPecas

não estou conseguindo fazer ele carregar na frmCadastroPecas ele mostra cod do fornecedor 0 alguém teria alguma solução

obrigado

Comment: tem sim cara.
Você tem duas maneiras legais de fazer:
1: Você pode criar um novo form (aspx) que quando o cara clicar no botão de pesquisar, abrir esse popup. Você vai conversando com a tela de baixo por session, por exemplo.
2: Outra maneira, que eu acho a melhor, criar um usercontrol. Esse pode ser aberto por modal (seria legal você usar o bootstrap). Se você não entendeu nada que eu falei, infelizmente você vai precisar procurar um exemplo na internet para saber como faz isso...

Comment: Isso é simples, cria tela com gridView, no evento form_load você carrega todos os fornecedores, no evento da click da grid você pega os dados do fornecedor e carrega na tela anterior, isso é a explicação basica. Ser for caso vai tentando fazer e postando as duvidas de cada passo.

Comment: se a resposta te ajudou, marque-a por favor

Answer (score 1):

vamos lá:

no form de pesquisa, crie uma propriedade FornecedorDTO para retorna-lo:

```
public FornecedorDTO Retorno {get;set;}
```

e imagino que o botão ok irá selecionar o fornecedor correto ? 
no código dele, faça assim:

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Retorno = (Aqui você atribui o objeto selecionado)
      this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
}
```

agora no form do cadastro:

```
 private void pctLocalizaFornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     frmPesquisarFornecedor pesqFornec = new frmPesquisarFornecedor();
     if (pesqFornec.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
     {
        "seucampoFornecedor".Text = pesqFornec.Retorno.Codigo;
        //Carrega os outros campos
     }
     //se não entrar no if, não faz nada porque a pesquisa foi cancelada.
 }
```