# Como transportar informações do datagridview para um textbox em outro form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com a seguinte questão na minha aplicação. Tenho o form1 e nesse form1 tenho dois textbox, o txt_cod.text e o txt_fornec.text e um botão de pesquisa, quando clico no botão de pesquisa deste form1, chamo o form2 que me traz um datagridview populado com duas colunas, a coluna de cod_fornecedor e nome do Fornecedor.

Agora o que preciso, que quando o usuário dar um duplo click na linha do datagridview, ele transportar as informações da linha selecionada para o form1 dentro de suas textbox expecificas, ex. coluna cod_fornecedor dentro o txt_cod.text e a coluna nome fornecedor dentro do txt_fornec.text do form1.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55565/pegar-o-dados-pesquisafornecedor-e-colocar-no-form-cadastro-de-produtos/198267#198267

Comment: Muito obrigado Rovann, vc mesmo ja tinha me ajudado em uma pergunta igualzinha que eu mesmo tinha feito, me desculpa mas não me lembrava, e isso ai deu certinho aqui muito obrigado.

Comment: sem problemas, abç

Comment: Agora como faço pra ele não abrir outro form principal, por exemplo abri o form principal chamei o form secundário cliquei na linha e ele esta abrindo outro form principal e não levando a informação para o forme principal que já esta aberto, como fazer pra ele abrir só um form.

Comment: olha este exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55565/pegar-o-dados-pesquisafornecedor-e-colocar-no-form-cadastro-de-produtos/198267#198267 ... no seu form principal, você tem que abrir o secundário como showdialog e no seu secundário, quando escolher, dar o `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` e não abrir outro form

Comment: Rovann faço como me informou não traz nada no form principal.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63157/discussion-between-rovann-linhalis-and-junior-guerreiro).